# how do I convert ['2 1', '2 1'] to [['1 ', '2'], ['2 ', '1']] in python?

Tags: python

I need to perform a conversion from a list in this way `['2 1 ', '2 1']` for this otherwise `[['1 ', '2'], ['2 ', '1']]` in Python and would whether there is any command to perform this operation?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the meaning of this question. Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: The placement of the quotes in the first example seems off, is it intentional?

Comment: Try something with line.split(' ')

Comment: I don't see how you expect to get from one of those to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = ['2 1', '2 1']
res = [item.split() for item in data]
res[0] = res[0][::-1]

[['2', '1'], ['2', '1']]
```